# Drupal 6 PHP: Foreach keeps repeating action on same row

Tags: php, drupal, foreach, row, repeat

I've don a site in Drupal 6, and am trying to make some spans with different classes to print in my .tpl (html).

In the example I have two people listed in their own row. They both have two arrays with different values called 'positions' and 'preferred positions'.

My problem is that I've made a foreach, and it prints the spans, but it keeps **repeating** the spans each time for the ame row (in this there is only two rows). I can't seem to find the error in my code. Please have a look, any help, or a finger pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
foreach ($vars['view']->result as $key => $row) {
    // preferred positions on pitch             
$outputspanpref = "";           
    foreach ($row->node_data_field_pref_position_field_pref_position_value as $key =>
        $position) {
            $keyclass = 'pref-position-' . $key; 
        $positionclass = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$position['value']));
            $outputspanpref .= '<span class="' . $keyclass . ' ' . "pref-position" . 
            '' . $positionclass . '"></span>';      
        $vars['prefposition'] = $outputspanpref;        
    }

    // secondary positions on pitch 

    $outputspan = "";

    foreach ($row->node_data_field_position_field_position_value as $key => 
        $position) {
            $keyclass = 'position-' . $key; 
        $positionclass = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$position['value']));
        $outputspan .= '<span class="' . $keyclass . ' ' . $positionclass.'
                </span>';           
        $vars['position'] = $outputspan;        
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: @rootatwc: While it may be also on-topic on drupal.stackexchange.com, it is still fully on-topic here ... even more as the problem seems to be not Drupal-specific at all.

Comment: @rootatwc - this is just a general PHP programming question and isn't really Drupal specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're re-using `$key` within nested `foreach` loops. Try using `$key1`, then `$key2`, etc for each subsequent loop.

```
foreach ($vars['view']->result as $key1 => $row) { // 1st forloop
foreach ($row->node_data_field_pref_position_field_pref_position_value as $key2 => $position) { // 2nd forloop
foreach ($row->node_data_field_position_field_position_value as $key3 => $position) { // 3rd forloop
```

Comment: Fixed it like this:  foreach ($vars['view']->result as $row) {
 

  
  $outputspanpref = "";
  $playerNID = $row->node_node_data_field_playername_nid;

   foreach ($row->node_data_field_pref_position_field_pref_position_value as $key => $position) {
  
  $keyclass = 'pref-position-' . $key; 
  $positionclass = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$position['value']));
  
  $outputspanpref .= '<span class="tooltip3 ' . $keyclass . ' ' . "pref-position" . ' ' . $positionclass . '"><span>Left back</span></span>';
 
  $vars['prefposition'][$playerNID] = $outputspanpref;
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

Based on your problem description. It is likely that you are using the same reference in your loop and thus to rectify it ,you must assign each row to it's own unique variable.